# android open gallery via intent ACTION_PICK vs ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

in my app i would like to have the user choose an image from the gallery and retrieve the result (thumbnail + full image uri). i would also like the user to be able to choose which gallery app to open (i.e. default gallery app or some other gallery app).

initially, according to this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) by google i copied and pasted this code:

```
public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GET);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GET && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = data.getParcelable("data");
        Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
        // Do work with photo saved at fullPhotoUri
        ...
    }
}
```

while it does get me the thumbnail and the full Uri in `onActivityResult(...)`, the problem is that it does not open a chooser for the user to select which gallery app to use and instead it opens this thing (see images below), which i assume is a default "image-chooser" thing where you could select another app via a menu.

[image][image]

i feel it's silly that the user would have to open this default "image chooser" first and once they are already in an "image chooser", select the gallery app that they actually want to use (sure, the user could just choose the image from this thing, but i want to give them a convenient choice).

so i changed my code to this and it does indeed display a proper chooser for the user and he can go straight to hes favorite gallery app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            startActivityForResult(intent, Utils.REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_GALLERY);
        }
```

however now i have a new problem: in `onActivityResult(...)` the line `data.getParcelable("data");` returns null. in other words, i don't get back a thumbnail.

i also tried

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

but "extras" is null.

is it possible to have a proper "app chooser" **AND** get back a thumbnail?

Comment: you can try out this cropping library which has the image picker https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 thanks ill give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

> however now i have a new problem: in onActivityResult(...) the line data.getParcelable("data"); returns null. in other words, i don't get back a thumbnail.

You do not get that from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, either. You can tell this by reading [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). It is certainly possible that there are some buggy `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities that happen to return a thumbnail `Bitmap` in a `"data"` extra, but you should not assume that any user will have such a buggy `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity, let alone choose it. Besides, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not limited to images; what would a "thumbnail" be of `application/json` or `text/csv` be?

Likewise, if you read [the documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), you will see that there is no discussion of a thumbnail.

> is it possible to have a proper "app chooser" AND get back a thumbnail?

No, insofar as you do not get a thumbnail back from anything except `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and that is for taking photos.

Comment: well, according to the link i provided in the question, google do say that this is the way to retrieve a thumbnail (under "File Storage"-"Retrieve a specific type of file") and i do indeed get a thumbnail back (dont know if its supposed to happen or its just a "buggy activity" like you say). i agree with what you said about GET_CONTENT not being limited to images, but i can narrow it down using "CATEGORY_OPENABLE"

Comment: @or_dvir: "google do say that this is the way to retrieve a thumbnail" -- most likely, that is a copy/paste bug in that training guide. "i agree with what you said about GET_CONTENT not being limited to images, but i can narrow it down using "CATEGORY_OPENABLE"" -- `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` is not related to the MIME type of the content, and `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` will not force developers to return a thumbnail from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activities.

Comment: a copy-paste error in the guide is definitely possible... can someone else confirm this please?

Comment: @or_dvir: You can confirm it yourself. Choose an image using the Storage Access Framework UI (you described it as "a default "image-chooser" thing"). On Android 7.1, the `Intent` returned to `onActivityResult()` for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has no extras (tested on a Nexus 5X with a slightly-modified version of [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Consumer) to force it to use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and check the extras).